# How can I request for a question to be reopened which was incorrectly closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I once answered a question [Too many images in one directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185101/too-many-images-in-one-directory/). I suggested Shotwell to create sub-folders.

And later on, I flagged [Is there a terminal command to split a folder in two?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190088/is-there-a-terminal-command-to-split-a-folder-in-two) as a possible duplicate  and later one was closed as an exact duplicate by [jrg](https://askubuntu.com/users/6005/jrg).

After thinking about it, I think those questions are not the same. Question one asks

> What is the simplest way to see the previews of these images?

Question 2 asks

> Is there a terminal command I could use to split it in two equal
>   folders so it would be easier for Nautilus to open one of them? Or
>   maybe 4 folders?

Granted they both want to open / preview pictures in a folder which contains images of a half a million/80.000. but they are not exact duplicates!

Now my question is, how can I vote to reopen these question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [3000 or more reputation point](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/close-questions) to have re-open voting privilege. For now, you can try posting in the [meta site](http://meta.askubuntu.com) or discussing the issue in the [Ask Ubuntu general chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201).

Comment: Crap i need 800- rep, well... challenge accepted (http://i2.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/004/457/challenge.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can flag the question with the  brief description of supporting arguments. Moderator will review the question

If you have further doubts, you can ask in meta(here)