# Requesting reopening specific question incorrectly closed as a duplicate of question closed as too broad

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[Remove audio from mp4 file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462769/remove-audio-from-mp4-file?noredirect=1) is asking a specific question and demonstrates that user tried to find a solution.

It was closed as duplicate of [What's video converters are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27864/whats-video-converters-are-available-for-ubuntu) despite that conversion between sane video formats will not remove sound and that this question is closed as too broad.

---

I am posting here as recommeded by [How can I request for a question to be reopened which was incorrectly closed as a duplicate?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4099/how-can-i-request-for-a-question-to-be-reopened-which-was-incorrectly-closed-as)

> For now, you can try posting in the meta site

Comment: Why do you want it reopened? I tend to agree that the duplicate is very poor but the question is almost six years old and had no interaction from then until your comment, do you plan to answer it?.

Comment: Because I wanted to know this, I googled it and it was without without answers due to trigger happy closing. Now I found a good answer and I am unable to properly post it as it is closed. Also, trigger happy unvalid closings as duplicates as one of the biggest problems with SE (in addition to company owning site going weird in last months)

Comment: OK if you want to answer it, that is possibly the best reason to reopen it. I will give it a reopen vote but it takes 5 users with 3k rep or a mod to do it, it may take a little time, if others agree.

Comment: Small point, do you want to remove the audio from the video (have a video with no audio, what that question asks) or extract the audio to its own file? If the latter, you could write and answer your own question and I don't think anyone would think the two things are the same and as far as I can tell, it wouldn't be a duplicate of anything on here.

Comment: Remove completely. I found the answer (on a different SE site) and linked it in the comment as I am unable to leave a proper answer.

Comment: I would like the question reopened as I have found an answer that addresses the OP's need and main issue. The syntax of the command is fine but the error message comes from a specific FFmpeg commit which was fixed shortly after. Commit that caused the issue: http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=dc6a17cf74a90e41d70ea1753cdb70c0a5b2ced8 and commit that fixed the issue here: http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=dc6a17cf74a90e41d70ea1753cdb70c0a5b2ced8. So the answer involves using a version of FFmpeg greater than 2.3.2. I have cast my own reopen vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a long and grueling battle, I am happy to report that this question has finally been re-opened.

Thank you to [Mark Kirby](https://askubuntu.com/users/75060/mark-kirby), [karel](https://askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel), [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan), and [Kulfy](https://askubuntu.com/users/816190/kulfy) for additionally casting reopen votes on the question.

Comment: And closed again as “needs details or clarity”…